# How to develop on top of sitecore habitat

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-habitat

In my next project I am planning to use modular approach using sitecore habitat . But I am not sure how to start with ? I have installed sitecore habitat and the local habitat site is running . Now I want to start with the actual application development But sitecore habitat has already a lot of out of box features which I don't need as I wanted to develop my own features based on requirement.
So can any body  please guide me how to start real time applications on top of sitecore habitat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore Habitat is a sample [solution](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat) implementing so called [Helix design principles](http://helix.sitecore.net/introduction/index.html). You should not build your solution *on top* of it, but you're welcome to use Habitat for inspiration.

Comment: Ok.Got it .Thanks .I just should follow helix principles in habitat way .